# How do I write the contents of a JTable to a text file?

Tags: java, parsing, jtable, filewriter, tablemodel

I have been working on a side project in which I have a JTable and need to write the contents of it to a text file. It is part of a JFrame in which there is an "update" button, which the user is supposed to click to update the text file. However, when I invoke the method to update the spreadsheet, all it creates is a blank file.

Here is the table model:

```
    spreadsheet.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false},
            {"", "0", false, false}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Descripton", "Amount", "Income?", "Expense?"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(spreadsheet);
```

And here is the method that converts the table to a text file:

```
private void updtSSActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer();
        TableModel tModel = spreadsheet.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < tModel.getRowCount(); i++) {

            Object cellValue = tModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
            fileContent.append(cellValue);
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("data.txt"));
        fileWriter.write(fileContent.toString());
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Spreadsheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

(I obtained the above method from here: https://community.oracle.com/message/5235252)

How do I fix this? I am still somewhat new to Java, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are only getting the value of the first column in your table model, and this seems to be empty `String`s. You would need to traverse every column for every row in your table model to create e.g. a `String` or `StringBuffer` that you could then write to your file.

You can call `getColumnCount()` on your table model to get the number of columns, then in the for loop you already created, do another loop where you traverse the columns for each row, assemble a `String` or `StringBuffer` that you append to your `fileContent` `StringBuffer`, and you might want to put a `\\n` as well after each row.

If the table model gets larger you might want to consider writing to a file on the fly instead of assembling in memory with a `StringBuffer`.